# How can I get OS/X-like switch windows of same program bound to hotkey with linux GUIs?

Tags: linux, gnome, hotkeys, window, ubuntu-unity

On OS/X, Command-~ switches between windows associated with the program with current focus. This is very handy when toggling through a set of browser windows or editor windows, for example.  A couple years ago I noticed someone using similar functionality on a Gnome linux laptop and they showed me how to set it up, but I forgot the details (so I know it's possible).

I frequently switch between MacBook and a variety of linux systems running Gnome, Unity, and occasionally KDE. My Google-fu failed so I turn to stack exchange: How do I bind Alt-~ or similar key to give me functionality to switch between windows of program with current focus with linux windows managers?

Comment: In GNOME 3, this is the default.

Comment: Last time I gave it a try, Gnome 3 made me sad (but I'm glad they at least got this nice feature right)

Comment: Interestingly, this is one of the more hated features, from what I've read.

Comment: In GNOME 2, Metacity has such a feature marked as "highly experimental" in GConf. Compiz seems to have it as "Next window (Group)" keybinding for the appropriate switcher plugin in `ccsm`. Unity might have it too, as it is built on top of Compiz.

Answer (score 1):

Unity already has this feature. Just use Alt+` to switch between windows of the same application.